# Get text from textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem I am doing on my chat and I wanna write anything to textarea and see it in alert but I dont know where is a problem with my actually code.

This is my html

```
<textarea id="msg"></textarea>
<button id="myButton" onclick="citaj();">Click</button>
```

and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function citaj () {
  alert(document.getElementById('msg').value );
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You could use jQuery's .val() ( http://api.jquery.com/val/ )
Also, you don't need to write the semicolon in the onClick attribute.
 - But it should work fine, maybe try clearing your cache?

Comment: Works fine [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/RJPG2/)!

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pZPjS/1/

Comment: he starts good with javascript and u tell him to write in jquery...pls.don't use jQuery before you don't know a little javascript.

Comment: @cocco Just mentioned that because he tagged this question with jQuery

Comment: you code is working fine :), what is problem..?

Comment: Here is working code http://jsfiddle.net/xDAMK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

By Using Jquery

```
var msg = $('#msg').val();
alert(msg);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mz84z/1/)

By Using Javascript

```
 function citaj () {
 alert(document.getElementById('msg').value );
 }
```

Comment: He uses pure JavaScript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

The is nothing wrong with your code

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mz84z/

make sure this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function citaj () {
    alert(document.getElementById('msg').value );
}
</script>
```

is in the `<head>` tag

Answer (score 0):

here is a full html

the code is working and javascript is the native code. jQuery is just an extension for modern functions and polyfill. if u don't need it don't use it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script>
function citaj(){
 alert(document.getElementById('msg').value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="msg"></textarea>
<button id="myButton" onclick="citaj();">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```